# Why is this DELETE query giving me a syntax error?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to delete rows from a table but keep getting a syntax error and I am not sure why.

This is my query: `DELETE * FROM questions WHERE catid = '680'`

This is my table structure:

```
id (primary key, auto increment)
question
catid
ordering
```

With above query I get this error:

```
There was an error running the query [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM questions WHERE catid = "680"' at line 1]
```

There are two rows in the table, one with catid = 680 and 679.

Comment: Please review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html

Comment: Typo: Remove the `*` after `DELETE`, i.e. use `DELETE FROM questions ...`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thank you, been a while since I used a delete query.

Comment: If you do a `DELETE` join, then aliases can appear after delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
DELETE FROM questions WHERE catid = '680'
```

Comment: OK, but this is really a typo question.

Answer (score 3):

Try below -

```
DELETE FROM questions 
  WHERE catid = 680
```

Comment: OK, but this is really a typo question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I think it's not typo quesiton, the OP does not know that * is not working with delete, anyway, my thoughts can be wrong too